# Strange behaviour of IE11 with onsubmit and two forms on a page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, onsubmit

This happens only with IE11

```
<script>
function validate_form1(){
}

function validate_form2(){
}
</script>    
<form action=some-target onsubmit="return validate_form1()"></form>
<form action=some-other-target onsubmit="return validate_form2()"></form>
```

When validate_form1() returns true the execution continues with validate_form2()
Why?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Does it happen in IE11 when you try out this demo I made: https://jsfiddle.net/ws7rLw3s/. If not, please create a jsfiddle demo that does have the issue that you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in IE11 (unless in compatibility mode).

The following work-around worked for me, using the submit button's onclick event to set a javascript variable, and then check its value inside the validate functions.

```
<script>
var pushed;
function validate_form1(){
 if (pushed == 'one') {
  ...
 }
}

function validate_form2(){
 if (pushed == 'two') {
 ...
 }
}
</script>    
<form action=some-target onsubmit="return validate_form1()">
<input onclick="pushed='one';" type="submit" name="But1" value="Submit form1">
</form>

<form action=some-other-target onsubmit="return validate_form2()">
<input onclick="pushed='two';" type="submit" name="But2" value="Submit form2">
</form>
```